# How to trim image in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Can we cut image into half vertically without messing with width and height of the image as we can cut corners using `clip(CutCornerShape(50.dp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`clip`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clip(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) modifier takes any [`Shape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Shape), you can create your own, for example like this:

```kotlin
object HalfSizeShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline = Outline.Rectangle(
        Rect(Offset.Zero, Size(size.width / 2, size.height))
    )
}
```

I'm not sure if I cut the right part of the image for you, but you should catch the idea.

Using the same technique, you can create any shape described by a `Path`. Also you can add parameters to your `Shape` like this:

```kotlin
class HalfSizeShape(val widthPart: Float) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline = Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
        addRect(Rect(Offset.Zero, Size(size.width * widthPart, size.height)))
    })
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
Modifier.clip(HalfSizeShape)
```

Comment: How can I use my custom width which changes according to the state of the app?

Comment: @GetPythonCode you can replace `object` with `class`, add parameters into the class constructor, and calculate outline depending on those params.

Comment: Can you do me a favor Just give an example of how to use when I changed from Object to Class ?

Comment: Can we change the direction of trim. I means to say that right now it trims the right half part of the image but Can change the direction to trim the left half part of the image

Comment: @GetPythonCode specify offset of rect, like `Rect(Offset(x = size.width * (1 - widthPart), y = 0f), Size(width = size.width * widthPart, height = size.height))`

Comment: Is this will work as the previous one? Just the opposite side

Comment: @GetPythonCode sure, why don't you try it?